# About updating a View using in iPhone using Objective C

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, core-graphics

I have a scene, called testScene, it works like this:

```
@interface testScene : myScene {
 IBOutlet UIView *subview;
 IBOutlet UIView *drawingCanvasView;
 IBOutlet UIButton *update;
}

- (void)updateDrawingCanvas: (id) sender;
```

and when the user click the button,  update, it will run the updateDrawingCanvas method.
So, I have a drawingCanvasView, which gave a drawingCanvas.h, and .m, it like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface DrawingCanvasView : UIView {
 CGImageRef image;

}

-(void)setNeedsDisplayInRect:(CGContextRef)context;

@end
```

In the DrawingCanvasView, I have a drawRect method like this:

```
 CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
 CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0); 
 CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor); 
 CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0.0f, 0.0f);
 CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 100.0f, 100.0f); 
 CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

And I want the user click the button, and execute this, so I added a new method called setNeedsDisplayInRect:

```
 CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
 CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0); 
 CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor yellowColor].CGColor); 
 CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0.0f, 0.0f);
 CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 200.0f, 200.0f); 
 CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

But I can't called that in my updateDrawingCanvas method, it work like this:

```
- (void)updateDrawingCanvas: (id) sender{
 NSLog(@"loaded");
 [DrawingCanvasView setNeedsDisplayInRect:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
}
```

It my logic / concept right? or something I did wrong, thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't overwrite `setNeedsDisplayInRect:`. You implement the drawing code in `drawRect:` and when you call `setNeedsDisplayInRect:` the framework will ensure that your `drawRect:` gets called.

Comment: I can drawRect: , but I can't update the view... ...The system will call the drawRect again, if I called  [DrawingCanvasView setNeedsDisplay]; again?

Comment: What do you mean by "I can drawRect:"? You should never call `drawRect:`.

Comment: So, I should do everything about drawing in drawRect:, but I can't called the drawRect: directly?

Comment: That's correct. Just call `setNeedsDisplayInRect:` or `setNeedsDisplay:` and the framework will call `drawRect:` for you.

Comment: Why Apple design the UIView in this way?

Comment: Tattat: The documentation explains why. http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH8-SW53